# Silverstripe FulltextSearchable converts the table Engines to MyIsam

Tags: php, silverstripe

For Adding SiteSearch Functionality, When I Enable FullTextSearchable in Silverstripe, it converts the Page tables to MyISAM by default, But I need to Keep the tables InnoDB only.
I am using MySQL Version > 5.6(So, it does support FullText)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've pointed out InnoDB does support Fulltext search since version MySQL version 5.6, however the `MySQLSchemaManager` that comes with framework prevents you from using InnoDB for tables with fulltext indexes defined. Perhaps you can raise an issue on GitHub. You can create your own SchemaManager without this restriction (by extending `MySQLSchemaManager` and overriding `alterTable()`):

```
# Compare this to https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.5/model/connect/MySQLSchemaManager.php#L100
class MyCustomSchemaManager extends MySQLSchemaManager
{

    public function alterTable($tableName, $newFields = null, $newIndexes = null, $alteredFields = null,
                               $alteredIndexes = null, $alteredOptions = null, $advancedOptions = null
    ) {
        if ($this->isView($tableName)) {
            $this->alterationMessage(
                sprintf("Table %s not changed as it is a view", $tableName),
                "changed"
            );
            return;
        }
        $alterList = array();

        if ($newFields) {
            foreach ($newFields as $k => $v) {
                $alterList[] .= "ADD \"$k\" $v";
            }
        }
        if ($newIndexes) {
            foreach ($newIndexes as $k => $v) {
                $alterList[] .= "ADD " . $this->getIndexSqlDefinition($k, $v);
            }
        }
        if ($alteredFields) {
            foreach ($alteredFields as $k => $v) {
                $alterList[] .= "CHANGE \"$k\" \"$k\" $v";
            }
        }
        if ($alteredIndexes) {
            foreach ($alteredIndexes as $k => $v) {
                $alterList[] .= "DROP INDEX \"$k\"";
                $alterList[] .= "ADD " . $this->getIndexSqlDefinition($k, $v);
            }
        }

        $dbID = self::ID;
        if ($alteredOptions && isset($alteredOptions[$dbID])) {
            $this->query(sprintf("ALTER TABLE \"%s\" %s", $tableName, $alteredOptions[$dbID]));
            $this->alterationMessage(
                sprintf("Table %s options changed: %s", $tableName, $alteredOptions[$dbID]),
                "changed"
            );
        }

        $alterations = implode(",\n", $alterList);
        $this->query("ALTER TABLE \"$tableName\" $alterations");
    }

}
```

Then you can use `Injector` to use your custom class:

```
# Config.yml
Injector:
  MySQLSchemaManager:
    class: MyCustomSchemaManager
```

You should now be able to use the static `create_table_options` to force InnoDB engine, and create the fulltext indexes through the `indexes` static.

Example:

```
# SomePage.php    

/**
 * Force InnoDB database engine.
 *
 * @var array
 */
private static $create_table_options = [
    'MySQLDatabase' => 'ENGINE=InnoDB'
];

/** 
 * Define what fulltext indexes to create.
 *
 * @var array
 */
private static $indexes = [
    'SearchFields' => [
        'type' => 'fulltext',
        'name' => 'SearchFields',
        'value' => '"MyField", "Tags"',
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Fulltext search is only available in MyISAM. It's one of the primary advantages MyISAM has over InnoDB. Relevant: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam

Comment: Yes, InnoDB did not support it until MySQL v5.6. But, for mysql version above 5.6. It does support FullText Search.

Comment: The Reason I want all the tables to be in InnoDB is that it may cause problem for the automated backups on AWS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html#Overview.BackupDeviceRestrictions